# Skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then $A - A^T$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity: what does using the whole long method where I shall use a matrix mean?

Comment: Just take the transpose of the thing and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

Skew symmetric means that $A^t = -A$. So in your case $$(A - A^t)^t = A^t - (A^t)^t = A^t - A = -(A - A^t)$$ since the operation of transposition is linear and involutory.